# not able to use a variable as a global variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho, messagebroker

I have a mqtt broker which I am connecting through python.

I want to check if I am able to connect to my broker and trigger a mail if my connection is successful.

I intend to use a global variable `connected` and if this is false after trying to connect I trigger an alarm.

My code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 
import time

broker_address="ip"
port = "port"

global connected


def mqttConnection():
    connected = False
    print(connected)
    client = mqtt.Client("BrokerCheck",clean_session=True) #create new instance
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    print('Connecting to broker')
    client.connect(broker_address, port=port) #connect to broker

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("connected OK Returned code=",rc)
        connected = True
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    mqttConnection()
    time.sleep(60)
    if connected:
        pass
    else:
        #trigger an alarm
```

But I have a problem with my global variable connected. Am I using it in a right way?

Comment: The assignment to `connected` creates a local variable that shadows the global of the same name within the scope defined by `mqttConnection`.

Comment: where you able to connect with broker_address="ip", port = "port" declared as variables and then passing them to connect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the variable as global within the scope of each function that you want to assign to it from. For example:

```py
connected = None

def mqttConnection():
    global connected
    connected = False
    print(connected)
    client = mqtt.Client("BrokerCheck",clean_session=True) #create new instance
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    print('Connecting to broker')
    client.connect(broker_address, port=port) #connect to broker

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global connected
    if rc==0:
        print("connected OK Returned code=",rc)
        connected = True
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)
```

Basically, python functions are able to read any variables declared outside the function, but as soon as that function *assigns* to the variable, a new variable is created in local scope that overrides the one in global scope. The `global` operation disables this and allows you to assign to the actual global variable rather than create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your case:

```
x = 1
def foo(y):
  global x
  # Changing x locally will change the global value
  print(x)
```